# LINQ to hash - can't get the casting right!

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-entities

I have a table in SQL Server with 3 columns, a domain, a key and a value.  I'd like to end up with a hash that I can use in dot-net.  I'm using EF 4.0.

at first I tried:

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> myHash = db.Registries
  .Where(x => x.Domain == "Pricing")
  .Select(x => new { Key = x.Key, Value = x.Value });
```

which complains:

> Error 3   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)    C:\Users\ekkis\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SkillScore\Website\Controllers\HomeController.cs   53  21  Website

so obviously the type of the select needs to be tweaked.  I've messed with it for half an hour (I'm so useless!) without being able to make it work (God I miss IRC).  help anyone?

Comment: yes, I did try: .Select(x => (Dictionary<string, string>) new {...})

Comment: I also tried .Select().Cast<Dictionary<string, string>>() - which, as we know complains that it can only cast to EF native types

Comment: this also fails: .Select(x => new Dictionary<string, string>() { x.Key, x.Value }) - No overload method for 'Add' takes 1 arguments

Comment: this complains that there's no definition for 'Key': .Select(x => new Dictionary<string, string>() { Key = x.Key, Value = x.Value })

Comment: @ekkis: You will want `ToDictionary()` to create a Dictionary from linq -see my answer.

Comment: and, yes, this other style also fails: List<Dictionary<string, string>> myHash = from x in db.Registries where x.Domain == "Pricing" select new { x.Key, x.Value };

Comment: I'm still scratching my head over why you would WANT a list-of-dictionaries?... It would appear to me that (for a single domain) a Dictionary is all you'd need (keys-->values) within that domain. And for multiple domains, I guess you'd probably want a dictionary-of-dictionaries (domain-->(key-->value)). Cheers. Keith.

Comment: ok... I tried this: .Where(x => x.Domain == "Pricing").ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value); and .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x.Value) and .ToDictionary<Dictionary<string, string>(x => x.Key, x => x.Value)

Comment: @BrokenGlass - I thought perhas it's the ultimate cast I need so I tried: .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value).ToList() and .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value).ToList<Dictionary<string, string>() but nothing works... Christ this is so difficult... can I pleeeease go back to perl??

Comment: @corlettk - you're right.  I only need a dictionary.  that may help with my casting nightmare

Comment: the result of a ToDictionary is a dictionary, not a List. so change the result type to `Dictionary<string,string>` and see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like this is what you need:

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> myHash = db.Registries
                                            .GroupBy(x => x.Domain)
                                            .Select(g => g.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, 
                                                                        x => x.Value))
                                            .ToList() ;
```

This creates a separate dictionary for each domain and puts them all in a list. This is not entirely useful though, since you lose the information about the domain name - maybe a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,string>>` would be more what you want (having the domain name as key of the outer dictionary).

A dictionary for a single domain you can get by using `ToDictionary()` directly:

```
var pricingDictionary = db.Registries
                          .Where(x => x.Domain == "Pricing")
                          .ToDictionary( x => x.Key, 
                                         x => x.Value);
```

Note that pricingDictionary  is of type `Dictionary<string, string>` so if you need the full type you can do:

```
Dictionary<string, string> myHash = db.Registries
                                      .Where(x => x.Domain == "Pricing")
                                      .ToDictionary( x => x.Key, 
                                                     x => x.Value);
```

Comment: that's it!  god.  so much struggle just because I don't know.  a million thanks, it's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I got interested in: "How to build a dictionary-of-dictionaries in a LINQ query".

Here's my humble attempt, which is **untested** because I don't a LINQ-DB, because I don't have IIS, because I can't intall IIS for "Genuine" reasons some might guess.

Please feel free to edit this code to fix it (if it's broke).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var registries = FetchAllRegistries();
            foreach ( KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string,string>> domain in registries ) {
                Console.WriteLine("Domain: "+domain.Key);
                foreach ( KeyValuePair<string,string> entry in domain.Value ) {
                    Console.WriteLine("  "+entry.Key+" "+entry.Value);
                }                
            }
        }

        private static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> FetchAllRegistries() {
            return db.Registries
                .GroupBy(x => x.Domain)
                .Select(g => g.ToDictionary(
                    d => d.Domain,
                    d => d.ToDictionary(
                        kv => kv.Key,
                        kv => kv.Value
                    )
                ))
            ;
        }

        private static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> FetchRegistry(string domainName) {
            return db.Registries
                .Where(x => x.Domain == domainName)
                .ToDictionary(
                    x => x.Key
                  , x => x.Value
                );
        }

    }

}
```

And Forgive me: These queries just add credence to my opinion that LINQ is sooooo ugly that it's posteriour should be shaved, and it should be taught to walk backwards. True: the "long-hand" version IS a LOT more verbose, BUT it's also a LOT more self-explanatory. I suppose my perspective is that "LINQ is grand. Shame about the STEEEEEEP learning curve".

And, yes please... lets all go back to Perl cgi-scripts. Bless me father, for I cannot inheret... I'm in love with a commoner. Sigh.

Cheers. Keith.

Comment: laughing... I guess I'm like those 21st century hippies that never left the 70s and drive brand-new Volvos with a peace sign on the bumper.  I'm being dragged into the new world kicking and screaming